# PHP running AJAX script works only once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this strange issue, happening to my PHP script, On page load the AJAX script runs and also after the second time the AJAX script runs it works and sends data to PHP, but i seem to not understand why the PHP script doesn't process the incoming POST request the second time it is sent in when i clean the input text box and type again, i get a blank response.My code for more expatiation.

index.php :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="searchmedia(this)" placeholder="Search for seller with UNIQUE ID or Name.">

<div id="resut" style="margin-top:-24px!important;">
    //where the ajax result is returned
</div>
<div style="margin-top:-24px!important;" id="normal">
    //bla bla data here
</div>
<div id="hui" style="display:none;"><img src="../ajax5.gif">
</div>

<script>
    function searchmedia(e) {
        var tuq = $(e).val();
        if (tuq == "") {
            $('#resut').hide();
            $('#normal').show();
            $('#hui').hide();
        } else {
            $('#normal').hide();
            $('#hui').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sellersmessageajax.php',
                data: {tuq: tuq},
                timeout: 5000,
                cache: false,
                success: function (r) {
//console.log(r); 
                    $('#resut').html(r);
                    $('#normal').hide();
                    $('#hui').hide();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Could not search, reload the page and try again.");
                    $('#normal').show();
                    $('#hui').hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

sellersmessageajax.php :

```
<?php include('../connect.php'); ?>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['tuq']))
{

    $term = $_POST['tuq'];

    $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,
        $term); //WHEN I ALERT HERE THE SECOND TIME I SEE THE INPUT TEXT DATA THAT CAME IN BUT PLEASE CHECK AFTER THE **FOREACH**


    $condition = '';
    $query     = explode(" ", $term);
    foreach ($query as $text)
    {
        $condition .= "name LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,
                $text) . "%' OR reign_uniqeer LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $text) . "%' OR ";
    }

//WHEN I ALERT HERE I GET NOTHING

    $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);
    $zobo      = "ORDER BY name";
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM sellers_login WHERE " . $condition . $zobo;
    $result    = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $v_ida            = $row['id'];
            $v_namea          = $row['name'];
            $v_reign_uniqeera = $row['reign_uniqeer'];
            ?>

            <div style="border-bottom:0.1px solid #eee;padding-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;">
                <a class="zuka" title="<?php echo $v_ida ?>" id="<?php echo $v_ida ?>"
                   style="color:#666;text-decoration:none;outline:none!important;cursor:pointer;">
                    <b style="color:blue;"><?php echo $v_namea ?></b>
                    <br/>
                    <div style="height:auto;max-height:30px;">
                        <b>UNIQUE ID :</b> <b style="color:red;"><?php echo $v_reign_uniqeera ?></b>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <h1 class="zuka" style="text-align:center;margin-top:20%;"> No result found.</h1>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please correctly format your code. That's not nice to read!

Comment: `WHEN I ALERT HERE I GET NOTHING` php does not have an alert function, that is JS also where is this js function called from? `searchmedia()`  Communication is always from the client to the server.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It's called from `onkeyup="searchmedia(this)"` in the first input field.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Have you checked the Network tab to see if the AJAX requests are being sent, and what the raw response is?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It is called from OnkeyUp event in the input type  "text"

Comment: @Barmar Nothing no errors, if not it would not work at the first time it returns result the first time, but i don't know why the query doesn't run  the second time, confused to the core.

Comment: What about the Network tab, does it show the AJAX request being sent the 2nd and 3rd time?

Comment: oh, I never use events bound to attributes... silly me.

Comment: Could you try this that doesn't execute mysql query in php just print sql statement and what it gives you. Maybe then we can help you.

Comment: Not that this is your issue, but why are you using `onKeyUp`? Also, I'm not sure if it is case sensitive, and in your post you have `onkeyup` in all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Second time after clearing the data result set to hide. second time data is returning but it's hide

Add this line in **ajax success** block

```
$('#resut').show(); // Add this line
```

Answer (score -2):

you are sending the var tuq wrongfully. Try this:

```
 data :  {"tuq": tuq}
```

Comment: There's no difference. Quotes are optional around the key of a Javascript object literal unless it contains special characters.

Comment: And if you think quotes are required, why didn't you put quotes around `data`?